# adjuntar varios archivos de una carpeta de drive y enviarlos como pdf por correo con google script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

Soy nuevo en Google Apps Scripts y requiero adjuntar los archivos pdf y enviarlos por correo. He visto como realizar el envió y se envía el email con el último archivo cargado en la carpeta y lo que requiero es enviar hasta 3 de los archivos que se cargan en esa carpeta ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
function myFunction2() {
  // Send an email with two attachments: a file from Google Drive (as a PDF) and an HTML file.
var idFolder = '1o3zxezBal8MfrgoFPjq_iodbOYKjHRlY'
var container = DriveApp.getFolderById(idFolder);
var files = container.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);

//En esta parte se ingresa a un arreglo la información
  var archivosarray = new Array();
  var j = 0;
  
  var archivos = container.getFiles();
    while (archivos.hasNext()) {  
      var file = archivos.next();
      //var links = file.getDownloadUrl();
      Logger.log(file);
archivosarray[j]=file;
    j++} 

  var a = archivosarray.join('\n');
  Logger.log(a);  

GmailApp.sendEmail('jlgarcia@gmail.com.gt', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
});

}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia

```
archivosarray[j]=file;
```

por

```
archivosarray[j] = file.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
```

y

```
 attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
```

por

```
 attachments: archivosarray,
```